# Excel Chart: There's a way to change Y-Axis values putting "mask" texts in place numbers?

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a chart that tells me how many time a task has been executed, considering that a task can be executed in different periods during a year.

I create the chart bellow.

[image]

I need to change the Y-Axis values putting in place the name of each task.
Instead "1", change to "Task 1" and so on.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the chart to the source format and use the following format for those cells under the custom formatting. Just make sure the cell values are actually 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

`_("Task "* #,##0_);_("Task "* (#,##0);_("Task "* "-"??_);_(@_)`